# Discord.js - Post image from folder ERROR

Tags: random, directory, discord.js

I want my bot to respond with an image if someone uses the command `!image`.
This image needs to be a random image from a specific folder named `gta`.

My code:

```js
client.on("message",message=>{
  if(message.content==('!imagetest')){
    var files = fs.readdirSync('./gta/')
    var chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)] 
    console.log(chosenFile)
    message.channel.send(
      {
        files : [
          chosenFile
        ]
      }
    )
  }
})
```

The error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/container/d864050.jpg'

It think should be `/home/container/gta/...` (a random image),
but i don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and split `chosenFile` by '/' and add 'gta/' between '/container/' and 'd864050.jpg'.

Something like this:

```
...
var chosenFile = files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)]
const arr = chosenFile.split("/")
var returnMsg = `/${arr[0]}/${arr[1]}/gta/${arr[2]}`
...
```